# Selenium get_attribute

Tags: python, selenium

The docs speak's http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html to me:

get_attribute(name)
Args:
name - Name of the attribute/property to retrieve.

Some of the args I know are textContent, innerHTML, outerHTML, href. Where can I find a list of the supported args?

Comment: Selenium retrieves HTML tag attributes, but the attributes you mentioned are JavaScript methods/properties. There is a pretty large set of HTML attributes - and what makes the answer harder is that you can even define your own [ones](http://w3c.github.io/html/single-page.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes). So basically it's kind of free text argument.

Answer (score 2):

Each HTML tag may have different attributes. You can see list of attributes of each tag from http://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp then go to each tag. Moreover, you can define custom attribute for any tags e.g. `<a custom-att="my customer value">Test</a>`.